# In jQuery find matching value in set of elements and return that element

Tags: jquery

I have a data-node-id attribute on body

```
<body data-node-id="1093>
```

I also have what could be a matching id in the following collection under `.navItemParent`

```
<div class="row small-up-5 navItemParent">
    <div class="column navItem">
        <a href="/" data-node-id="1093"><span class="topLineNav">Dining</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="column navItem">
        <a href="/" data-node-id="1111"><span class="topLineNav">Dining</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="column navItem">
        <a href="/" data-node-id="1211"><span class="topLineNav">Dining</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically I need to see if any `data-node-id` on the `a` tag matches the current value on the `body` tag.

I tried (the if condition below)

```
    if ($(".navItemParent").find(" .navItem a").data("node-id") === $("body").data("node-id")) {
        $(".navItemParent").find("a.active").removeClass("active");
        $(".navItemParent .navItem a").addClass("active");
    };
```

Comment: And where's the jQuery code you tried?

Comment: Have just added the code I tried @j08691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it I think:

```
var matches = $(".navItemParent").find('a[data-node-id="' + $("body").data("node-id") + '"]');
alert("Found " + matches.length + " results");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `body` node ID, then find all elements with a matching node ID:

```
var bodyNodeID = $("body").data("nodeId");
var matchingNodeElements = $(".navItemParent").find("[data-node-id='" + bodyNodeID + "']");
```

Answer (score 1):

Grab the id, build an selector with it and ask jQuery to do the work

```
var node_id = $(document.body).attr("data-node-id"),
    element = $('.navItemParent').find('a[data-node-id="' + node_id + '"]');
```

Or with vanilla JS

```
var node_id = document.body.getAttribute("data-node-id"),
    element = document.querySelector('.navItemParent a[data-node-id="' + node_id + '"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass that value from the body as the selector for Jquery:

```js
var nodebody = $('body').data('node-id');
$('a[data-node-id="'+nodebody+'"]').css('color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body data-node-id="1093">
<div class="row small-up-5 navItemParent">
    <div class="column navItem">
        <a href="/" data-node-id="1093"><span class="topLineNav">Dining</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="column navItem">
        <a href="/" data-node-id="1111"><span class="topLineNav">Dining</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="column navItem">
        <a href="/" data-node-id="1211"><span class="topLineNav">Dining</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var elementExists=$("a[data-node-id='" + $("body").data("node-id") + "']").length > 0; // will return true if found
```

This will be the selector: `$("a[data-node-id='" + $("body").data("node-id") + "']")`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of the jQuery [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and [`attr` function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to check if there is at least an `a` item whose "data-node-id" attribute is the same of the `body`'s one.

```js
$(function() {
  // demo: just to add the `data-node-id` attribute to the `body` tag
  $("body").attr("data-node-id", "1093");

  alert($("a[data-node-id = '" + $("body").attr("data-node-id") + "']").length > 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row small-up-5 navItemParent">
  <div class="column navItem">
    <a href="/" data-node-id="1093"><span class="topLineNav">Dining</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="column navItem">
    <a href="/" data-node-id="1111"><span class="topLineNav">Dining</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="column navItem">
    <a href="/" data-node-id="1211"><span class="topLineNav">Dining</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```